FBX export is not showing all animations
I have a model with several animations on it using various methods (basic object movement keyframes, and an armature pose). I am also Mirroring these.
It looks like the issue is that Blender has created an Action for each one of these individually, including the mirrored animations. All I want is for the exported FBX to display all of my animations in a single, looping animation. What can I do to combine these so that I can view this on Sketchfab?
